# Angular error 404 not found sending json to backend

Tags: json, angular, frontend, http-status-code-404

I'm learning frontend and backend right now, I tried to search for this error but I didn´t see anyone sending json to backend.
I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHbqz.png)  error

I'm not sure if that is because of the URL. If i try that URL and Json in postman it worsk fine, it is inserted on the database.
[Postman prove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykTYu.png)

It is basically a register page. I don't know why I get that error if the url is the same on postman and in browser, I'm sending the same data too,

This is the code:

User.service.ts

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
        import { Observable } from "rxjs";
        import { User } from "../models/user";
        import { global } from "./global";
    @Injectable()
    export class UserService{
        public url: string;
    
        constructor(
            public _http: HttpClient
        ){
            this.url = global.url;
        }
    
        test(){
            return "Hola mundo Servicio";
        }
    
        register(user): Observable<any>{
            let json = JSON.stringify(user);
            let params = 'json='+json;
    
            let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            console.log(json);
            console.log(params);
            console.log(headers);
    
            return this._http.post(this.url+'register', params, {headers: headers});
        }
}
```

global.ts

```
export var global = {
url: 'http://api-rest-laravel.com.devel/api/'}
```

register.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { UserService } from "../../services/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    public page_title: string;
  public user: User;

  constructor(
      private _userService: UserService
    ) {
    this.page_title = 'Regístrate';
    this.user = new User(1, '', '', 'ROLE_USER', '', '', '', '');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onSubmit(form){
  console.log('Componente de registro');
    console.log(this._userService.test());
    this._userService.register(this.user).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        form.reset(); 
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );

  
  }

}
```

app.module.ts (if needed)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error/error.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: have you checked for CORS issue ? check your network tab and see if options request is working. Also have a look at the api logs when you make that register request from angular app.

Comment: I saw that i needed to add code lines into index.php. header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); and access-control lines. It was already on the index.php though, I guess it is not enough. I will search some info about that, thanks